# Order by ID in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

Is there a way to have Raven order the results of a query by the Id field as if it was in integer.  So "cars/2" would come before "cars/11" if I did this query:

```
var cars = session.Query<Car>().OrderBy(c => c.ID);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the id of the document to be sortable in any way.
Add a CreatedAt property or something similar and use that

Comment: what if you are copying a field/entity from sql also called Id and are assigning the ids in-code? (ie mirroring the data) - it appears if you set up an index using `SortOptions.Int` and map `entity.Id` then `OrderBy` does not respect the `SortOptions` - if you change the name of the column to something else say `SortId` and keep everything else the same, sorting by int will then work but then the column names dont match up