# RavenDB Sort Order

Tags: sql-order-by, ravendb

Im playing around with ravendb trying to create a blog.

Im using Ravens own ID meaning that a document can look like this:

```
BlogPosts/1
{
  "Title": "Ny post",
  "Text": "Nytt blogginlägg",
  "Kategori": "spel"
}
```

I fetch all my BlogPosts with this code:

```
var blogPosts = Session.Query<BlogPost>().ToList();
```

In my view, I loop through all the Blogposts like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.BlogPosts)
                                        {
                                            <div class="media">

                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                    <h3 class="media-heading">@item.Title</h3>
                                                    <p>@item.Text</p>
                                                </div>

                                                <a class="view-info" href="#"><span>@item.Kategori</span></a>


                                            </div>
                                        }
```

My problem is this, everytime I create a new blogpost, the blogpost is given an ID higher than the one created before...In my view, I would like to display the blogpost with the higest number(the newest) first.

Can I use a sortOrder on this line maybe?

```
var blogPosts = Session.Query<BlogPost>().ToList();
```

Comment: Beware that `Query<BlogPost>().ToList()` will only pull back 1024 by default. This is honouring the 'safe-by-default' principles that RavenDB is designed behind. Page the data if you need more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var blogPosts = Session.Query<BlogPost>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Though note that this will sort alphanumerically, so probably won't give the result you desire.  See this answer from Ayende: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6149231/54222

Comment: Thank you! I sorted it out by giving all the blogposts a dateTime and then sorting after that, Thanks!

Comment: Note that sorting by text-based IDs will not work, because `BlogPosts/123` will appear *after* `BlogPosts/1123`.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz Indeed, that's way I said that in my answer :-)